# C# タイトルバー以外の場所でフォームをドラッグさせる方法について

Tags: c#, winforms

お世話になります。

タイトルバーを持たないフォームでドラッグ移動をさせようと、下記のサイト様
http://dobon.net/vb/dotnet/form/moveform.html
を拝見してソースを組んでいるのですが、二つ目のサンプル、コントロール上でも
移動できるようにするでは、すべてが同じフォームの中に存在しているので、
このコードでもできると思うのですが、自分で別にクラス化したユーザコントロールを
貼り付けた場合、どのようなコードにすればよいでしょうか。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
既にクラス化されているので、図のようにラベルやピクチャボックスに後から
MouseDownやMouseMoveの処理を追加することはできません。それなら、
クラス化するときにラベルやピクチャボックスにMouseDownやMouseMoveの処理を
追加しておけばよいかというと、本来必要でない(フォームではないので、
持って動かすという処理はこの時点では必要ない)処理を入れるのはふさわしくないと
思います。

やはり、この自作のユーザーコントロールをフォームに張り付けた後、
フォーム側のコードからMouseDownやMouseMoveの処理を実装したいのですが、
通常通りにやると、ラベルやピクチャボックスでドラッグすると、
それらのコントロールにマウス処理が働いてしまい、うまくいきません。
サンプルに書かれてある内容通りです。

力ずくでやるのであれば、ラベルやピクチャボックスにフォームからアクセスすれば
できそうではありますが、あまりきれいなコードにはならないと思っています。

図のラベルやピクチャボックスの場所でも、ドラッグ移動できるようにするきれいな方法を
ご教授いただけますでしょうか。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Label`や`PictureBox`のイベントハンドラーで`UserControl`のイベントを発生させればよいのでは。

```
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
    private void label1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        var c = (Control)sender;
        base.OnMouseDown(new MouseEventArgs(e.Button, e.Clicks, c.Left + e.X, c.Top + e.Y, e.Delta));
    }

    private void label1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        var c = (Control)sender;
        base.OnMouseMove(new MouseEventArgs(e.Button, e.Clicks, c.Left + e.X, c.Top + e.Y, e.Delta));
    }
}
```

### 追記

`UserControl`上のコントロールでマウスイベントを無視する手段としては、`WndProc`をオーバーライドしてヒットテストを無視する方法があります。

```
class CustomLabel : Label
{
    private const int WM_NCHITTEST = 0x84;
    private const int HTTRANSPARENT = -1;

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message message)
    {
        if (message.Msg == (int)WM_NCHITTEST)
        {
            message.Result = (IntPtr)HTTRANSPARENT;
        }
        else
        {
            base.WndProc(ref message);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: いつもありがとうございます。教えていただいた方法で、希望する通りの動きはできました。ただ、やはりこの方法では、クラス化する時点で、ラベルやピクチャボックスにあらかじめ処理を記述しておかなければなりません。クラス化するコードのほうでは、ラベルやピクチャボックスは表示として用いるだけ、つまり、マウスなどの処理をできれば加えたくないのですが、やはりどうしてもこの方法でないとそれはできないのでしょうか。つまり、クラス側では、『ラベルやピクチャボックスからはマウスイベントを受け取らず、そのまま下のフォームにイベントを投げてしまう』みたいな方法があれば幸いなのですが。フォームのKeyReleaseプロパティのようなもの…でしょうか。

Comment: @たたぱた 少なくとも`UserControl`か`Label`のどちらかで対処する必要があるわけですが、子コントロール側を派生クラスにすることでヒットテストに反応しないようにもできます。

Comment: 何度もありがとうございます。方法はまちがっていないのですが、やはりそれぞれのコントロールに手を加えなければならないのは一緒のようですね。今回はラベルとピクチャボックスだけでしたが、それ以外のコントロールにも同様のことをしなければいけない場合、それぞれに同じ処理ょ追加した継承クラスが必要になってしまうわけで、手順の多さからすると、あまりふさわしくないように思えます。一番最初に教えていただいた方法で、コツコツ実装させてみます。ありがとうございました。今後ともよろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0):

きれいな方法ではないですが、あとから全体的にWindowメッセージを処理したいのであれば、
WH_GETMESSAGEでSetWindowsHookExを使用して、
GetMessageをフックして必要な処理を行う方法もあります。